# joomla administrator redirects back to login page and password of super user changes automatically

Tags: joomla

http://www.omknowledgeacademy.com/administrator/

- if i enter correct username and password it redirects back to login page.
- I changed password in users table of super user as md5 to say A
- Then i login with super user username n password that i set
- the password changes automatically to something like this different each    time
  $2y$10$nF/d4g50h/RaMoAjK0vdLe5jFQsw/6dyTqodsnTWqd8JMTX5LdJ6i
- Not able to login in admin panel
- Also it redirects back to http://www.omknowledgeacademy.com/administrator/index.php

Comment: Have you tried clearing the #__sessions table? Have you removed your .htaccess file and see if the problem persists?

Comment: yes i did still the same